# Xpath unable to get the value from SPAN

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I tried this, i am getting empty response:

```
sample=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/app-root/div/app-visual-code/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[3]/span[2]')
for elem in sample:
    test1=elem.text
    print(test1)
```

[image]

Comment: That loop is odd.  You haven't shown us what `test` is, and the loop variable `elem` is never used...

Comment: I assume you have to to do this:
for elem in sample:
    test1=elem.text
    print(test1)

Comment: I have done this, for elem in test:
    test1=elem.text
    print(test1)

Answer (score 0):

If that span is the only one with `class="manual-code"` then you could try using a simpler xpath expression like

```
sample=driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//div[@class='manual-code-section']/span[@class='manual-code']")
```